# Deleting the old entry and asking for a new one in while-loop doesn´t work

Tags: python, tkinter, button, while-loop

I have the problem in my program that I can enter a number and it compares it with the given number, but then immediately says that all attempts have been used up. I think that deleting the entry and asking for a new entry (in the while-loop) doesn't work as intended.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def yes():

    window_2 = Tk()
    window_2.title("Zahlenraten")
    versuch = Entry(window_2, width=20)
    versuch.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    
    def play(versuch = versuch):
        
        window_3 = Tk()
        window_3.title("Zahlenraten")
        label3 = Label(window_3, text = "Meine Zahl liegt zwischen 1 und 10.")
        label3.grid(row = 1, columnspan = 2)
        label4 = Label(window_3, text = "Gib deine Zahl ein:")
        label4.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        
        i=0
        x = random.randint(1,10)
        tries = float(versuch.get())
        while i <= tries:

            eingabe = Entry(window_3, width=20)
            eingabe.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
            
            def guess(eingabe = eingabe, tries = tries, i=i, x=x):
                entry = float(eingabe.get())
                label2 = Label(window_3, text = "Das ist dein Versuch: " + str(i)+" Die Zufallszahl lautet: " + str(x))
                label2.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
                
                if i == tries:
                    label3.config(text = "Du hast alle Versuche aufgebraucht!")
                else:
                    if entry > x:
                        label3.config(text = "Deine Zahl ist zu groß.")
                    elif entry < x:
                        label3.config(text = "Deine Zahl ist zu klein.")
                    else:
                        label3.config(text = "Du hast gewonnen!")

            eingabe.delete(0, END)
            i=i+1
            button5 = Button(window_3, text="Bestätigen", command = guess).grid(row = 3)

        window_3.mainloop()

    button3 = Button(window_2, text="Confirm", command = play).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    label1 = Label(window_2, text = "Wie viele Versuche möchtest du haben?").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    window_2.mainloop()

def no():
    window_1 = Tk()
    window_1.title("Abbruch")
    label1 = Label(window_1, text = "Bist du dir sicher, dass du das Spiel abbrechen möchtest?").grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
    button3 = Button(window_1, text="Yes", command = window_1.quit).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    button4 = Button(window_1, text ="No", command = yes).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

window = Tk()
window.title("Zahlenraten")
label = Label(window, text = "Do you want to play with me?").grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
button1 = Button(window, text="Yes", command = yes).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
button2 = Button(window, text ="No", command = no).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
```

Comment: Nothing in the `while i <= tries` loop waits until a button is pressed. The loop just runs quickly until `i == tries`. I guess it would need some work to rewrite the code in a proper event-driven way.